# What is the RFC or Standard for Apache Subversion

Tags: svn, standards-compliance

I'm tasked with finding the standard or RFC that defines Subversion SVN.

I've had a look-see on the project web page

- [Subversion Docs](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/)

Something on

- [Standard practices for Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566892/standard-practices-for-subversion)

and in wikipedia

- [Subversion wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion)

Nothing to say if there's a compliance or conformance that an implementation needs to meet.  Any ideas?  Or is the answer simple, "no"?

Comment: The Right Answer is "nothing"

Comment: SVNBook: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: One interjection.  When you are working in a regulated industry, the answer can *rarely* be *nothing*.  If it is, then one can be asked to jump through a multitude of hoops for the `governance brownies`.  That's quite painful to be honest; because you can't code until . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the quick comments; I have a satisfactory answer.  If your project needs to establish *bona fides*, conformance, etc.  you can start with the wikipedia entry under Software Engineering:

- [Software Configuration Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management)

The main citation for:

- [828-2012](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109%2FIEEESTD.2012.6170935) **[IEEE Standard for Configuration Management in Systems and Software Engineering](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109%2FIEEESTD.2012.6170935)** [2012. doi:10.1109/IEEESTD.2012.6170935. ISBN 978-0-7381-7232-3.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109%2FIEEESTD.2012.6170935)

and also

- ISO/IEC/IEEE STD 12207-2008 **[Standard for Systems and Software Engineering - Software Life Cycle Processes](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4475826&queryText=ISO%2FIEC%2FIEEE%2012207:2008&refinements=4293284673&searchField=Search_All)**, 2008
- ISO/IEC/IEEE STD 15288-2008 **[Systems and Software Engineering - System Life Cycle Processes](http://%20ISO/IEC/IEEE%20Systems%20and%20Software%20Engineering%20-%20System%20Life%20Cycle%20Processes)**, 2008

That's sufficient for my purposes.  Hopefully it will give others a start.